# Certain external Images (google drive) not caching on iOS Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, caching, browser, safari

Demo:
http://c.atara.net/simple.html

When You click Show 1 and Show 2 on a Desktop Browser the background changes immediately, because I assume, the images are already loaded on the page (cached)

However on an iPad or iPhone, the images don't seem to cache .The background turns white first and there is a pause while each image loads. I think this may have something to do with the images being hosted on Google Drive (they are redirected?).

Can anyone come up with any way to get the images to cache on the mobile browser? I can't host them anywhere else.

I am looking for any solution no matter how crazy-- such as if theres a javascript way to turn the images into base64 and then cache that.

Here is the revelant code

```
<img id="one" src="http://docs.google.com/uc?id=0ByWN3asD9NWSS3pIOHBTb2MzeVE">
<img id="two" src="http://docs.google.com/uc?id=0ByWN3asD9NWSYlRzdElIMC02VFU">


<script>
$(function(){

$('.show').on('click',function(){
var newid=$(this).data('show');
var showJQ=$('#'+newid); 
$('#background,#pictureframe').show();
$('#background').css("background-image", "url('"+showJQ.attr('src')+"')"); 

})
```

Thank you!!!